# Exception while using String.Format "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."

Tags: c#, arrays, string.format

I have an array

```
ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
array.Add("a");
array.Add("b");
array.Add("c");
```

and I have a string variable **refFormat** which has the format as below.

```
string refFormat = "{2} {0}";
```

I'm trying to get a string of values from the array with this format. Below is what I have written.

```
string newStr = String.Format(refFormat,array.ToArray());
```

I'm getting the following exception when I'm trying to do this.

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

I know this question sounds repeated but my doubt is how to pick the values from the array whose indexes are the ones specified in the format that **2** and **0**. Please help..

**Edit**: Hi sorry for putting up the wrong question. I'm using an arraylist instead of a string array I'm trying the same. I'm still getting the exception in spite of converting it to an array using ToArray(). Where am I going wrong? And also I cannot use List instead of arraylist here since the array contains data of different type. Please help me out..

Comment: Are you sure you get this exception on `string newStr = String.Format(refFormat,array);` line? [It shouldn't throw any excetion based on your code](http://ideone.com/N2ZwRA) and `newStr` will be `c a`.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce that error, but my code worked. I used the exact same code from your question, I made no changes.

Comment: For reference, `string` does have the following method available `public static string Format(string format, params object[] args)`. So the question is using a valid method i.e. passing an array as the 2nd parameter.

Comment: Well, this code works fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sQUxiu

Comment: I want it to be **c** and **a**. That is where it is failing.

Comment: @Andrei Didn't know about dotNetFiddle. Looks like a great resource.

Comment: Actually I've used **ArrayList** instead of **string[]**. Might that be the reason whyy it is failing?

Comment: @AkshathaPatil, of course this is the reason. `ArrayList` falls into a different overload, Format(string, object) I believe. This is also the reason why everyone is advised to put *actual code* into the question

Comment: Why use `ArrayList`? If you insist, you can copy the `ArrayList` over to a new array with `.ToArray()` instance method.

Comment: This works perfectly. Maybe you delete an element from the `ArrayList` before using `String.Format()`... so my suggestion is to check the size (e.g. `if(array.Count >= 3){...}`) before using `String.Format()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, here is my working code too:

```
string[] array = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

string refFormat = "{2} {0}";

string newStr = String.Format(refFormat, array);

Console.WriteLine(newStr);
```

I did not encounter an error when running the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the parameters correctly , it needs to be indexed as {0} {1} and so ons

```
String.Format(refFormat,array[2],array[0]);
```

Comment: Both are valid ways of doing what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

For string arrays, I see no reason the syntax shouldn't work.  I had the same issue, however, with an int array, and that gets gnarly.  Tl;dr: int is not an object type, so it will never resolve to the open-ended `(string format, params object[] args)` overload and instead tries to use `(string format, object arg0)` overload.  Broader discussion and some theoretical workarounds at [Using an array as argument for string.Format()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885239/using-an-array-as-argument-for-string-format)