# Using an array as argument for string.Format()

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, string-formatting

When trying to use an array as an argument for the `string.Format()` method, I get the following error:

> FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

The code is as follows:

```
place = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4};
infoText.text = string.Format("Player1: {0} \n Player2: {1} \n Player3: {2} \n Player4: {3}", place);
```

The Array contains four values and the arguments in the `String.Format()` are also the same.

What causes this error?

(The `infoText.text` is just a regular String object)

Comment: You're passing an `int[]` as opposed to a `string[]`

Comment: Perhaps something like `string.Format("Player1: {0} \n Player2: {1} \n Player3: {2} \n Player4: {3}", place[0], place[1], place[2], place[3]);`
It works as you pass an object relating every {} in string

Comment: Just for the record, instead of using string.format, you could create the string more dynamically without hardcoding the number of players, e.g.: `infoText.text = string.Join("\n", place.Select((p,i) => $"Player{i+1}: {p}"));`

Comment: @Me.Name That looks really good. I will try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can convert int array to string array as pass it using `System.Linq` `Select()` extension method.

```
infoText.text = string.Format("Player1: {0} \nPlayer2: {1} \nPlayer3: {2} \nPlayer4: {3}", 
                              place.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

**Edit:**

In C# 6 and above, you can also able to use [`String Interpolation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation) instead of using `string.Format()`

```
infoText.text = $"Player1: {place[0]}\nPlayer2: {place[1]} \nPlayer3: {place[2]} \nPlayer4: {place[3]}";
```

Check this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nu2x5W) for your reference.

Comment: So the argument can be a `string[]` array but not an `int[]` array?

Comment: @martin36 not only `string[]` - your array should be an object or string type.

Answer (score 10):

Quick fix.

```
var place = new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

C# does not support co-variant array conversion from `int[]` to `object[]` therefor whole array is considered as `object`, hence [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.110).aspx) with a  single parameter is called.

Comment: C# _does_ support co-variant array conversion (e.g. from `string[]` to `object[]`), but in this case the conversion would also involve _boxing of value types_ which is why it won't work.

Comment: @Joey: he wrote _"does not support co-variant array conversion from int[] to object[]"_ ;-)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to pass an explicit array for a `params` argument, but it has to have the matching type. `string.Format` has a few overloads, of which the following two are interesting to us:

```
string.Format(string, params object[])
string.Format(string, object)
```

In your case treating the `int[]` as `object` is the only conversion that works, since an `int[]` cannot be implicitly (or explicitly) converted to `object[]`, so `string.Format` sees four placeholders, but only a single argument. You'd have to declare your array of the correct type

```
var place = new object[] {1,2,3,4};
```

Comment: What is the difference between `params object[]` and just a regular `object[] ` array?

Comment: @martin36: You can treat the `params` parameter as any number of arguments. The compiler will automatically wrap them in an array to call the method.

Answer (score 3):

As others have already said, you can't convert `int[]` to `object[]`. But you can fix this issue using `Enumerable.Cast<T>()`:

```
infoText.text = string.Format
(
      "Player1: {0} \n Player2: {1} \n Player3: {2} \n Player4: {3}",                        
      place.Cast<object>().ToArray()
);
```

BTW, if you're on C# 6 or above, you might consider using interpolated strings instead of `string.Format`:

```
infoText.text = $"Player1: {place[0]}\n Player 2: {place[1]} \n Player 3: {place[2]} \n Player 4: {place[3]}";
```

Comment: I am using Unity and it has only the version C# 2.

Comment: Oh sorry, but thanks for the answer anyways. I will remember it for later use.

Comment: @martin36 No problem, it might be an useful suggestion for other readers too :)