# Correct overload selection

Tags: c#

I have the code

```
//this runs 
string[] s_items = {"0","0"};
string s_output = string.Format("{0}{1}",s_items);

//this one throws a exception
int[] i_items = {0,0};          
string i_output = string.Format("{0}{1}",i_items);
```

why does the first one run and the second throw a exception? 
Why selects

`int[]` the [`Format(String, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.110).aspx) overload

`string[]` the [`Format(String, Object[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx) overload

Comment: have you tried using Int32 instead of int?

Comment: @Oswald it should not make any difference. `int` indstead of `Int32` is always perfectly legal.

Comment: @Oswald `int` is a C# alias for `Int32`

Comment: ok but to explain. The signature of Format is (String, Object) if you use int, it's a value type and object requires a reference type

Comment: @Toshi the exception is not displayed in question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an array as argument for string.Format()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885239/using-an-array-as-argument-for-string-format)

Comment: @Fabulous you're right, wrong langugage :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `string[]` can be converted to an `object[]` because they're both arrays of *reference types*. And all references are "equal". This is one of the nasty (array) conversions that is built into the C# language from day 1 and should not have existed but we didn't have generics and proper co/contravariance rules from day 1.

An `int[]` cannot be converted to an `object[]` because `int`s, the things actually contained in the first array, are not references.

Comment: My initial thought was to look at co[ntra]variance as the root cause initially but figured this behavior isn't new and precedes generics. Good call in your edit.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I'd be happier if there was no array variance, but they had to push out C#/.NET without generics and this was a sort of compromise.

Answer (score 3):

From the msdn documentation,

> This is a problem of compiler overload resolution. Because the compiler cannot convert an array of integers to an object array, it treats the integer array as a single argument, so it calls the Format(String, Object) method.

See more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Right `string.Format("{0}",i_items)` for instance infers `{0}` as ant int array, for instance.