# Printing out MAC address

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Just trying to use `string.Format()` to convert system MAC address to text format. But it's not working:

```
byte[] MacAddr = new byte[6];

// this works, but rather clumzy
mac = string.Format("{0:X2}-{1:X2}-{2:X2}-{3:X2}-{4:X2}-{5:X2}",            
          MacAddr[0], MacAddr[1], MacAddr[2], MacAddr[3], MacAddr[4], MacAddr[5]);

// give me index error
mac = string.Format("{0:X2}-{1:X2}-{2:X2}-{3:X2}-{4:X2}-{5:X2}", MacAddr);
```

Edit1: OK, I am wrong, but it seems `string.format` works for [this guy's case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721685/exception-while-using-string-format-index-zero-based-must-be-greater-than-or) with `string[]` .

I can see there is a overload method for `string.format`: 
`Format(String, array<Object>[]()[])`. Is it possble to create some form of byte[], that can be taken as this `array<Object>[]()[]` ?

Comment: What is the index error stating?

Comment: " Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.". It sounds like MacAddr is taken as a single object. not an array ?

Comment: Well yes, the second approach fails because you're referring to "argument 1", "argument 2" etc up to argument 5, but you've only provided a single argument (argument 0). You could use `BitConverter.ToString` instead, but otherwise stick with your first approach.

Comment: Makes you miss the spread operator in JavaScript :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the error occurs because you want to format 6 items but there is only 1 in your parameter list

```
//6 parameters expected, only one "MacAddr" given
mac = string.Format("{0:X2}-{1:X2}-{2:X2}-{3:X2}-{4:X2}-{5:X2}", MacAddr);
```

here is a shorter version compared to your working approach

```
mac = string.Join("-", MacAddr.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));
```

Comment: Thanks, where can I find reference to this `select` method ?

Comment: that's Linq [Select()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Those LINQ stuff looks very new to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you specify a format with 6 parameters but provide only one:

```
//expected 6 parameters, provided only one
mac = string.Format("{0:X2}-{1:X2}-{2:X2}-{3:X2}-{4:X2}-{5:X2}", MacAddr);
```

if you are working with C# 6.0, you can also work with string interpolation:

```
 //string interpolation
    mac = $"{MacAddr[0]}:X2-{MacAddr[1]}:X2-{MacAddr[2]}:X2-{MacAddr[3]}:X2-{MacAddr[4]}:X2-{MacAddr[5]}:X2";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only 1 parameter in your `string.Format()` function while it requires 6 parameters as per requirement. 
You can use `String.Join` for a better readable approach -

```
mac = string.Join("-", MacAddr.Select(x => x.ToString(":X2")));
```

Answer (score 0):

try `BitConverter`

```
mac = BitConverter.ToString(MacAddr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`BitConverter.ToString(byte[])` gets the exact string you want, although MAC addresses are usually separated by colons, not dashes.